# Boost serialization performance: text vs. binary format

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

Should I prefer binary serialization over ascii / text serialization if performance is an issue?

Has anybody tested it on a large amount of data?

Comment: Interesting topic. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558382/boostserialization-high-memory-consumption-during-serialization

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used boost.serialization to store matrices and vectors representing lookup tables and 
some meta data (strings) with an in memory size of about 200MByte.  IIRC for loading from 
disk into memory it took 3 minutes for the text archive vs. 4 seconds using the binary archive 
on WinXP.

Comment: 3 minutes sounds... inexplicably slow. Those weren't POD types :)

Answer (score 5):

Benchmarked it for a problem involving loading a large class containing lots (thousands) of nested archived classes.

To change the format, use archive streams

```
boost::archive::binary_oarchive
boost::archive::binary_iarchive
```

instead of

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive
boost::archive::text_iarchive
```

The code for loading the (binary) archive looks like:

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename", std::ios::binary);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive input_archive(ifs);
Class* p_object;
input_archive >> p_object;
```

The files and walltimes for an optimised gcc build of the above code snippet are:

- ascii: **820MB** (100%), **32.2** seconds (100%).
- binary: **620MB** (76%),  **14.7** seconds (46%).

This is from a solid state drive, without any stream compression.

So the gain in speed is larger than the file size would suggest, and you get an additional bonus using binary.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [protobuf - Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) if performance is an issue

["Protocol Buffers" from .Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)